# PropertyChanged event fires but UI not update

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

```
public string TenNguoiDung
{
   get { return _currentNguoiDung.TenNguoiDung; }
   set
       {
         _currentNguoiDung.TenNguoiDung = value != null 
           ? value.ToStandardString(true) : string.Empty;
         SendPropertyChanged("TenNguoiDung");
         ValidProperty(_currentNguoiDung.TenNguoiDung, new 
           ValidationContext(_currentNguoiDung) { MemberName = "TenNguoiDung" });
        }
 }

public static string ToStandardString(this string value,
                                      bool isAllStartWithUpper = false) 
{
   string result = string.Empty;
   value = value.Trim();
   var listWord = value.Split(' ').ToList();
   listWord.RemoveAll(p => p == string.Empty);

   foreach (var item in listWord) result += 
       item.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + item.Substring(1).ToLower() + " ";

   if (!isAllStartWithUpper) result = 
       result.Substring(0, 1) + result.Substring(1).ToLower();

   return  result.Trim();
}
```

I have a TextBox:

```
 <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="1" Text=
 "{Binding Path=TenNguoiDung,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
```

When i typed some clear text to Standard, Setter called SendPropertyChanged("TenNguoiDung") but on UI not update. How can i fix that??

**Edit:**

```
public void SendPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

**Edit:**

I debuged at **Setter**, i saw _currentNguoiDung.TenNguoiDung changed after **ToStandardString**, but on UI was not updated

**Update**
I used few hours to google and i got my answer.
I feel happy when this bug only happen on debug mode. When i run application without debug, it work perfect!!

Fix debug Mode:
[link][Coerce Value in Property Setter - Silverlight 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11965408/coerce-value-in-property-setter-silverlight-5[link])

1. Right click on the Web project in Solution Explorer and select
   Properties.
2. Select the Web tab.
3. Scroll down to the Debuggers section.
4. Uncheck the checkbox labelled Silverlight.

Comment: 1) Please add the code of SendPropertyChanged. 2) What is the class that contains this code? A view model or a code behind? 3) Make sure you have no binding errors.

Comment: @mot: thank for reply, 1) my func SendPropertyChanged is correct with other MyProperty, this bug orcurs when i using **value.ToStandardString()** at setter
2) this code in ViewModel
3) i'm sure binding no errors

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are setting the data context to the instance of the class containing your property.

From the looks of it you are doing this but make sure you are implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

When debugging if you have any binding errors happening these will show in the output window.

Is the value changing if you type in 'hello' and then replace it with 'world'? If so it may just be a case sensitivity issue

Comment: yes, i'm sure. My code work normaly until i add **.ToStandardString()** method at setter.

Example: when i type "YoU aRe goOd Guy" , UI automatical changed "You Are Good Guy"

Comment: "make sure you are implementing INotifyPropertyChanged" did it for me :)